# Reload UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind without reloading cellForItemAt

Tags: swift, swift5

I want to reload just footerView. If i use reloadData(), whole collectionView gets reloaded.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {

        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:

            if let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: MockupCollectionHeader.className, for: indexPath) as? MockupCollectionHeader {
            headerView.configure()
                headerView.titleLabel.text = baseLayout.properties?.titleString
            return headerView
            }
            return UICollectionReusableView()


        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:

            if let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: MockupCollectionFooter.className, for: indexPath) as? MockupCollectionFooter {
                footerView.configure()
                footerView.footerLabel.text = baseLayout.properties?.footerBody
                footerView.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(continueClicked(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
                footerView.checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
                footerView.isChecked = baseLayout.isCheckbox
            return footerView
            }
            return UICollectionReusableView()


        default:

            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
        
        return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Reloading all the visible data is not onerous or time-consuming. `cellForItemAt` never knows when it should be called and should be ready to run at any moment. So what's the issue?

Comment: I have checkbox in footerView. Am also using didSelectItemAt, after selecting different item if i click on footer checkBox, to update state of checkBox I am calling reloadData().  This will also trigger cellForItemAt and selected Item will be reverted. So, on click of checkBox I just  need to call viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind @matt